# Dynamic Scopes generator on ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, module, rubygems

I'm currently working on a gem for rails (not ruby) -> https://github.com/elentras/common_scopes

This gem should be generating scopes for ActiveRecord models, based on it's attributes types. By including it to the model; some default scopes will be generated for Boolean, String, Date, DateTime and Integer attributes.
In my mind, it could be pretty cool to use, and will ensure all models have the sames scopes by default without duplication. Used on an API, it should be a proper way to normalize filtering on all index methods. (used with has_scope for example)

**My problem :**

When I include it on a model, the scopes aren't available... 
I put a `binding.pry`on the failing test.

`rake test`

You can try to call my scope as below in the binding.pry instance :

`Actor.by_created_at(Date.today)`

To be working and thinking on the same elements, I propose to use as reference the `CommonScopes::ByDate` module.

I'm sure it's related to a bad design, but It seems I'm missing something and I don't understand it / why... Some help, please ?!